Bool union result changes after 'Apply Transfrom'
I'm not sure where the problem is. After I set up the Apply Transform operation, these two triangles cannot be unioned properly, which could have been union before.
Here is the .blend file. I add Error-one collection and Right-One collection.




"Flat" meshes (i.e. without thickness) are non-manifold. And the Boolean modifier might produce "odd glitches and artifacts" in such a case. Applying transformations is affecting the round-off errors, so a glitch might be created where there was none before.

I have found the problem. After executing the apply transform, the precision of XYZ caused an exception in boolean union.

for each vertices, do round(x,6) to limit the precision
